# bash script with awk filtering and query

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I need a little help to finish off a little code. I want to do a query with the `who` command, but I only want to see the users listed I give in arguments with username <s>and pts/num</s>, ordered by the time of login. It works for 1 user, but I would like to get it work with more users. Here it is atm:

```
#!/bin/bash
who |
awk '($1 ~ /'$*'/){print $3 $4" "$1" "$2}' |
sort -n |
awk '{ print $2, $3 }'
```

How can I make it work with multiple users?

Sample use:

```
./script username1 username2 blabla pete stevie
```

Comment: give an example how do you want to run it

Comment: ./script username1 username2 blabla pete stevie etc

Comment: another homework ? :)

Comment: I'm surprised that `...awk '($1 ~ /'${*// /\|/}'){...` doesn't work. At least in bash 3.2. My intent is to globally sub spaces with '|' chars, so the arg-list would be converted to an awk `OR` able expression, like  `/username1|username2|blabla|.../`. Can any bash-ites say if this is possible? Hm... doesn't work in RH ksh either. Good luck to all.

Comment: Post some sample input (i.e. output of `who` on your system) and expected output.

Comment: @shellter: It appears that you can can't substitute for the spaces introduced in/by `$*` directly.  `set -- abc def ghi 'jkl mno'; echo "${*// /|}"` yields `abc def ghi jkl|mno`.  You can do it indirectly: `y="$*"; echo "${y// /|}"` yields `abc|def|ghi|jkl|mno`.  So, I would work with `star="$*"; awk '(...'"${star// /|}"'...'`.  Take it away, maestro...

Comment: actually if i added 1 username in argument, i got it return fine, but when i put other username also, i got back error

Comment: umm thank you Jonathan Leffler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correct than for:

```
$ who
oxo    tty7         2014-05-12 14:32 (:0)
bar    pts/5        2014-05-12 18:35 (:0:S.1)
oxo    pts/1        2014-05-13 13:29 (:0:S.5)
baz    pts/8        2014-05-12 18:35 (:0:S.2)
oxo    pts/12       2014-05-12 18:35 (:0:S.3)
oxo    pts/13       2014-05-12 18:35 (:0:S.4)
foo    pts/15       2014-05-12 18:35 (:0:S.0)
bar    pts/17       2014-05-13 19:36 (:0:S.6)
bar    pts/18       2014-05-14 00:03 (:0:S.7)
```

you expect to get for example:

```
$ ./who.sh foo bar
bar pts/5
foo pts/15
bar pts/17
bar pts/18
```

If so than this will work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash    
users=`echo $@|tr " " "|"`
who|sort -k 3|awk -v users="$users" '$1 ~ users {print $1" "$2}'
```

Actually it could be done just in the `awk` witout any `tr` or `sort` but I hope it's good enough.

**UPDATE:**

To get rid of `tr` this can be used:

```
#!/bin/bash
who|sort -k 3|awk -v users="$*" 'BEGIN { regex = gensub(/\s/, "|" ,"g", users) }; $1 ~ regex { print $1" "$2 }'
```

You can use `asorti()` to replace `sort`.

Comment: what does the -k 3 on the sort? if it sorts by the 3rd column (yyyy-mm-dd), the 4th column (hh:mm) should be recognized as well. what if 2 users logged in the same day?

Comment: neaaaat, im testing on more boxes, on different who outputs. but who do you put | between the arguments?

Comment: there is a restricition by the teacher, the script should not create any files

Comment: i still dont get the gensub, what do you replace there?

Comment: but what does it do exactly? I dont get it why is it needed.

Comment: yup thats divide the usernames with a |, i already figured out the tr, but i dont know why do i need the | divisions? what is the purpose of the gensub() function? (/\s/, "|" ,"g", users) - this eaxactly, what does it do? users contain the usernames i type as parameters for the script ./script.sh param1 param2 etc goes into users

Comment: how does a | behave in regex? the tr version is still more understandable, tho i dont know what are the | used for, why do i have to use the |, i dont know. What do you mean on 'proper regex' and how do they disappear when i do the print?

Comment: hmm \s means whitespace, now im stuck on the meaning of the g char, step by step i ll figure it out:) so i have usernames in parameters with whitespaces in between

Comment: hahah i already done that, even in my native language, still dont get it exactly what it does. it is some kind of raplacing if something starts with the letter g. it replaces the whitespaces with |'s in users, if something starts with g, but what? :) the whole gensub()'a g in at the first letter? which equals with 'regex'

Comment: If the how argument is a string that does not begin with ‘g’ or ‘G’, or if it is a number that is less than or equal to zero, only one substitution is performed. - which means? :D